# How to show only a part of my page until someone makes a purchase

Tags: joomla-3.4, extensions, subscriptions, membership

Sorry for the confusing title. This is a little difficult to explain.

I would like to know how to show only 1/3 of my page until someone makes a purchase and then they can see the full page. Similar to how these guys do it at https://networklessons.com/.

Cheers

Carlton

Answer (score 1):

You can try with one extension for [Membership & Subscriptions](http://extensions.joomla.org/tags/membership-subscriptions).

- [RS Membership](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/e-commerce/membership-a-subscriptions/rsmembership)
  One of the functions is the restriction of portions of content or the full article.
- [Membership Pro](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/e-commerce/membership-a-subscriptions/membership-pro)
  Similar to the above extension, you can restrict portions or the full article.
- [Smart Subscriptions](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/e-commerce/membership-a-subscriptions/smart-subscriptions)
  With this free extension you can use the functionality with the "Read More" feature.

---

*Note: I am not affiliated in any way to the extensions mentioned above.*

Comment: Hello Alex. So I decided to purchase RS Membership. However, I don't see an option to restrict portions of a page from the examples listed here https://www.rsjoomla.com/video-tutorials/rsmembership.html

Comment: Hi, also you can see more info in this link: https://www.rsjoomla.com/support/documentation/rsmembership-user-guide/how-to/restrict-access-to-certain-parts-of-your-webpages.html